# How put off multiline block in a tag point with Jade template engine

Tags: pug

For example if i have the example code Jade view,

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    script.
        console.log("helloworld");
        console.log("helloworld2");
        console.log("helloworld3");
        console.log("helloworld4");
        console.log("helloworld5");
        console.log("helloworld6");
        console.log("helloworld7");
        console.log("helloworld8");
```

Html generated:

[image: example rendered jade]

How i can render it without multiline in this block?

Comment: Have you checked the answer? Does it work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    script
      each val in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        = '\n       console.log(\'helloworld'+val+'\');'
```

or this

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    script
      - var val=1
      while val < 6
        = '\n       console.log(\'helloworld'+ val++ +'\');'
```

which will render

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
       console.log('helloworld1');
       console.log('helloworld2');
       console.log('helloworld3');
       console.log('helloworld4');
       console.log('helloworld5');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To get exactly the output as state above use

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    script
      - var val=1
      = 'console.log(\'helloworld\');'
      while val < 9
        = '\nconsole.log(\'helloworld'+ val++ +'\');'
```

To omit newlines remove the `\n` in the last row of the template

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body
    script
      - var val=1
      = 'console.log(\'helloworld\');'
      while val < 9
        = 'console.log(\'helloworld'+ val++ +'\');'
```

Comment: Yes, this works but i want render literal javascript strict mode without newlines. In this case helloworld is a little example but  I want create instances class and call functions; for this reason an equal not resolve me the question. The equal only works per line.

Comment: So please adapt your example

Comment: I'm working in my [demo personal page](http://demo-joaquinglezsantos.c9.io) for tests on `cloud9`. In root you can see the rendered javascript in the HTML. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: So what you want be the out put is something like <div id="container-content"><ul id="listado" class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><strong>titulo 1</strong><p>titulo 1</p></li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>&lt;strong&gt;titulo 2&lt;/strong&gt;</strong><p>msg 2</p></li><li class="list-group-item"><strong>titulo 3</strong><p>msg 3</p></li> ... where the numbers within the strong tags shall count up, followed by the javascript nested inside the div?

Comment: No. Elements `.list-group-item` contain info title and msg readed by an api from dabatase postgresql. I want the script `Paginator` with functions `paginatorCallbefore` and `paginatorCallback` without newlines.

Comment: To make things a little bit easier to understand, would you mind to post some sourcecode as you want it to be compiled from the template? Please describe which parts should be generated dynamicaly.

Comment: simply, with the example of my question, the jade code must be without loops

Comment: So I missunderstood you totaly and your question is "How to write a template that takes a multiline input and renders an output that contains no newlines" ?

Comment: yes (even taking the code `app.locals.pretty = false;`)